# How do I use libcurl to printf a remote FTP directory listing?

Tags: c, libcurl

I think I'm supposed to use `CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY` but I'm not really sure how to proceed.

```
CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY, long listonly);
```

I'm not sure how to make the call to actually print the list.

Comment: you want a remote directory listing over which protocol? libcurl supports a lot of different protocols, and with some you don't necessarily get a directory listing (HTTP for example, gives directory lists on the good will of the server and generally only as formatted HTML pages, so not in a standardized format)

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention, need it for ftp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling the `CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY` option for FTP has the effect of retrieving only file names instead of file details (e.g. file size, date, etc.) basically as the difference between using a plain `ls` (only names) or a `ls -l` (listing with details) on UNIX. At the FTP protocol level, enabling `CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY` will make libcurl issue a `NLST` command rather than a `LIST`. Then to get the directory listing you do the same as a file transfer, with the difference that your `ftp://` URL will point to a directory (and not to a file). The contents of that transfer will be your directory listing.

To display the directory listing, rather than saving it to a file, you can use the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` option to have libcurl call a callback function you supply for every block of data. That function only needs to `fwrite` the data to `stdout` to display it. It should look something like this:

```
void write_callback(void* data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* ptr)
{
  fwrite(data, size, nmemb, stdout);
}

int main()
{
  // ...
  curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
  // ...
  ret = curl_easy_perform(handle);
}
```

Comment: okay thanks, how would i print it to command window directly instead of saving it to a file?

Comment: I added an example to the answer