# Using curl with an unpredictable target filename

Tags: bash, curl

The filename of my `curl` download target is unpredictable and globbing with an asterisk isn't possible. I can download the file using the following command, but ***only after I've determined its' name in advance***:

```
curl -O -vvv -k -u user:password https://myURL/ws/myfile.zip
```

How can I tailor my `curl` command to succeed with an unpredictable target name?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Comment: For those looking for a programming solution, see [How do I use libcurl to printf a remote FTP directory listing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34279893/608639)

Comment: @DavidDennis I've edited your question to what I ***believe*** the problem you were trying to solve to actually be. Listing files was an intermediate step to get around the problem of the unpredictable file name when specifying the target.  If I've misconstrued this, please revert my changes to how I've rephrased your question.

Answer (score 5):

There's no easy way to get a directory listing using HTTP. You can use curl to just print the HTML generated by the site. If there's an index with links to the files on that server, simply running

`curl -s -u user:password https://myURL/ws/ | grep .zip`

will print HTML-formatted links to the zip files available for download on that page.

Answer (score 1):

## Intro:

Like the OP, I had a similar issue scripting the download of a binary- for docker-compose- from Github because the version number keeps iterating making the file name unpredictable.

This is how I solved it. Might not be the tidiest solution, but if you have a more elegant way, ping me a comment and I'll update the answer.

## Solution:

I merely used an auto-populating variable that takes the output of `curl`, prints the 1st line- which will be the most recent release- and then`grep` for the release number prefaced by a "v". The result is saved to the the path `/home/ubuntu` as the arbitrary file name "***docker-compose-latest***"

```
curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/$(curl https://github.com/docker/compose/releases | grep -m1 '<a href="/docker/compose/releases/download/' | grep -o 'v[0-9:].[0-9].[0-9]')/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /home/ubuntu/docker-compose-latest
```

And we validate that we received the correct binary (I'm downloading to a Raspberry Pi which has an ARM processor on 64 bit Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

```
file /home/ubuntu/docker-compose-latest
```

Produces the following feedback on the file:

*/home/ubuntu/docker-compose-latest: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, Go BuildID=QqyJMzYMWOofWehXt3pb/T7U4zg-t8Xqz_11RybNZ/ukJOlZCpzQuZzBcwSK3b/d6ecQ2m2VfqKb_EQRUZA, stripped*

To validate this solution works, just execute the above commands remembering to change the path of the `file` command if not using Ubuntu.

## Conclusion:

Again, might not be the most elegant solution, but it's a solution for how one can download a target with `curl` that has an unpredictable filename.